# Which equation did Riemann use when proving $\zeta(-2)=0$

Tags: proof-verification, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Which equation did Riemann use when proving that $\zeta(-2)=0$. I know that the first trivial zero lies on the point $(-2,\,0)$ and would like to prove it using the same equation.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: For the "equation" for the trivial zeros see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726506/trivial-zeros-of-the-riemann-zeta-function). Where did Riemann prove that $\zeta(s)=0$?

Comment: I'm sorry, that made no sense. I mean't to say (-2)=0. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Riemann's_functional_equation

Answer (score 1):

He proved that $$\int_0^\infty x^{s-2}(\frac{x}{e^x-1}-\sum_{k\le K} \frac{B_k}{k!}x^k 1_{x > 1})dx = \Gamma(s)\zeta(s) -\sum_{k\le K} \frac{B_k}{k!}\frac1{s+k-1}$$
is analytic for $\Re(s) > -K$

where $\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_k \frac{B_k}{k!}x^k$ for $|x|< 2\pi$ thus $$\zeta(-k) = (-1)^k k! (s+k)\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)|_{s=-k} = \frac{(-1)^kB_{k+1}}{k+1}$$
As you see this is much easier than the functional equation.