# Any nice way to find $\zeta(n)$ where n is any positive even integer using integral calculus?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I actually found it exciting finding the sum of the infinite convergent series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{n^{2}} \right]$, $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{n^{4}} \right]$ and $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{n^{6}} \right]$ using Fourier series and Parseval's identity until I found out it can be generalized as $\zeta\left( s \right) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{n^{s}} \right] = \frac{2^{s - 1} \cdot \left| B_{s} \right| \cdot \pi^{s}}{s!}$ for any positive even integer.

> So my question is whether is it possible to prove it the same way using Parseval's identity for any non negative even integer $s$?

Comment: We don't know any closed form for $\zeta(n)$ when $n$ is odd. We know that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational but it is only a conjecture for $\zeta(n)$ when $n \geqslant 5$ is odd.

Comment: @Cactus sorry for the confusion sir but i actually meant it for non negative integers only 

Comment: @Cactus I don't know when it was put in, but at present OP is only asking about values of zeta at positive *even* integers, specifically via Parseval.

Comment: You mean prove the formula using Parseval's identity ? I don't know about that sorry.

Comment: @Ash_Blanc:  There's something wrong with the formula.  $n$ is a summation index.  It should not appear on the RHS.  Only $s$ and constants should be on the RHS.

Comment: For  negative integer $n$, the sum representation for $\zeta$ is no longer admissible. (it only "works" for $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 1$) You have to use different representations. See here for instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708219/zeta-function-for-nonpositive-integers.

Comment: Please show your derivation using Fourier series and Parseval's identity if you're asking if it can be generalized to $\zeta(n)=\frac{2^{n-1}|B_{n}|\pi^n}{n!}$ for any positive even integer $n$. Also, what do you mean by "prove it the same way"? The "same way" as what?

Comment: Yes, but it’s complicated: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.09326.pdf